# copy data from one node1 child to another node2 child with using firebase cloud functions

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

[image]

Below is my code of cloud functions I am trying to copy the data from users node to challenge node

```
exports.copyChallengeDate = functions.database.ref(`Users/{pushId}/DateChallengeAccept`).onCreate((snapshot, context)=>{
  var DateChallengeAccept = snapshot.val();
  console.log('Challenge', context.params.pushId, DateChallengeAccept);
  var challenge = DateChallengeAccept;

  return admin.database().ref('Challenge/' + context.params.pushId).child('DateChallengeAccept').set(challenge);

});
```

But the thing is when I am trying to copy the date from user table to challenge node it's only occur in QS5h99YxS0ZGpT42fpUFvzOdpTi1
D uid same as of Users node. I want to copy it in both uid's(QS5h99YxS0ZGpT42fpUFvzOdpTi1, 7aH9Ag8414VzM0n7P6ur4LvcepI2)
D present in challenge node. I was stuck in it from last two days please help me out

Comment: Can you add to your post what is the expected end result. It is not crystal clear what you want to do. Do you want to copy the Date to the Challenge node 7AH9... and to the node QS5h...??

Comment: I want to copy the date from users node to the challenge node in both the uid according to my code it's only copying in first uid  QS5h.. but I want to copy it in both the uid's.

Comment: I edited my question may be it is clear than before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update following you remark that `DateChallengeAccept` is not initialized **when you create the record**. You should use another method, like `onUpdate()` (or `onWrite()`) and not `onCreate()`, as you do in your question. Do as follows:

```
exports.copyChallengeDate = functions.database.ref(`Users/{pushId}`).onUpdate((change, context) => 

    const DateChallengeAccept = change.after.val().DateChallengeAccept;

    if ( DateChallengeAccept === undefined) { 
       return false;
    }

    const referredBy = change.after.val().referredBy;

    console.log('Challenge', context.params.pushId, DateChallengeAccept);

    const dateChallengeAcceptObj = {
        "DateChallengeAccept": DateChallengeAccept
    };

    let updates = {};
    updates['Challenge/' + context.params.pushId + '/DateChallengeAccept'] = dateChallengeAcceptObj;
    updates['Challenge/' + referredBy + '/DateChallengeAccept'] = dateChallengeAcceptObj;

    return admin.database().ref().update(updates);


});
```

---

You need to get the `referredId` value in your Function, because it is this data item that holds the ID of the other user (i.e. 7aH9Ag8414VzM0n7P6ur4LvcepI2). So you have to trigger the event on the parent node, not at the `DateChallengeAccept` node.

Then you have to use the `update()` method to write simultaneously to two nodes, see the doc here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#update_specific_fields

So you should do as follows:

```
exports.copyChallengeDate = functions.database.ref(`Users/{pushId}`).onCreate((snapshot, context)=>{

    const DateChallengeAccept = snapshot.val().DateChallengeAccept;

    if ( DateChallengeAccept === undefined) { 
       return false;
    }

    const referredBy = snapshot.val().referredBy;

    console.log('Challenge', context.params.pushId, DateChallengeAccept);

    const dateChallengeAcceptObj = {
        "DateChallengeAccept": DateChallengeAccept
    };

    let updates = {};
    updates['Challenge/' + context.params.pushId + '/DateChallengeAccept'] = dateChallengeAcceptObj;
    updates['Challenge/' + referredBy + '/DateChallengeAccept'] = dateChallengeAcceptObj;

    return admin.database().ref().update(updates);


});
```

Comment: Well the code you have suggested it seems to be work but it's showing the following errors  Error: Reference.update failed: First argument contains undefined in property 'Challenge.Nk5jfWfXLPX9D3eUgEE02wVdPcH2.DateChallengeAccept'
    at validateFirebaseData (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.node.cjs.js:1433:15)

Comment: Sorry this comes from a mistake in the code in the initial answer: we have to pass an object to the database. I've updated the code.

Comment: No it's not working it's showing the previous error only and no issues whenever you'll be able to answer its helpful bdw thank you for your answers

Comment: Can you verify that `snapshot.val().DateChallengeAccept` is not undefined?

Comment: I've also changed the code from `DateChallengeAccept: DateChallengeAccept` to `"DateChallengeAccept": DateChallengeAccept`. But I am not 100%s sure it will make a difference, just give a try!

Comment: initially it is undefined but when I click on button DateChallengeAccept field created in the user table only in one uid and on the same button click I want to copy the date in challenge node in both the uids

Comment: and I want only after clicking button all action will be triggered simultaneously.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172686/discussion-between-divyank-vijayvergiya-and-renaud-tarnec).

Comment: I've updated the answer in the light of the fact that DateChallengeAccept is not initialized at creation.

Comment: @DivyankVijayvergiya Hi, did you have time to look at the updated answer.  Do you think you could considering upvoting and/or accepting this detailed answer? Thanks.

Comment: Hey man I am sorry I was not well from last two days so it's working for me. Thank you so much for your suppport man.